# C# Preview crystal report can not open in another computer

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am using C# 2010 Pro, SQL Server Management Studio 2008, and Crystal report 2013

I was already success got print preview with Crystal reports in my computer, but I got an error when I try to open in another computer, when I just click on button "Print" (call print preview with crystal report).

This is my error when I click on button "Print":

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

Thank you so much.

Comment: Your error message pretty much tells you where to start. Does the other computer have access to the SQL instance? Does the user have permissions? Does the server allow remote connections?

Comment: On the computer you run it you have not access to the database, you should check the connection.

Comment: i can access database from another PC, but only crystal report i cant access, i think its error in dataset ?

Comment: Post part of your code that can help us see the problem, but surely the problem is in the connection string to the database.